# OptaPlanner: Chained Through Timing, Automatic Delay Until Last Paradigm

Tags: java, optaplanner

The OptaPlanner docs suggest using a custom variable listener to implement an automatic delay when, for example, more than one person must be at a job site at the same time:

https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/design-patterns/design-patterns.html#chainedThroughTimeAutomaticDelayUntilLast

This requires that the planning entities must know about each other regardless of anchor, however, and in a chained timing scenario, the entities in a chain only know about `previous`, `next`, and the `anchor`.  At least by default.

This means that the shadow variables that are being updated depend on the planning *and shadow* variables of entities in chains other than their own.

So, is there a standard to handling this?  I could have the entities hold references to the other entities, but that doesn't explain how one can prevent variable listener or score corruption.

I'd imagine that this requires specifying sources on other chains, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the whole solution in your custom shadow variable listener through the score director:

```java
public class MyDelayedStarTimeVariableListener implements VariableListener<MySolution, MyEntity> {

    // ...other before/after methods omitted...

    @Override
    public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<MySolution> scoreDirector, MyEntity entity) {
        MySolution solution = scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution();

        // Next, get any entity from the solution.
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```java
@PlanningEntity
public class MyEntity {
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "myAnchorRange", "myEntityRange" }, graphType = PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED)
    private MyEntityOrAnchor previous;

    @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = MyDelayedStarTimeVariableListener.class, sources = {
            @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "previous") })
    private LocalTime startTime;

    // Rest of the class omitted for brevity.
}
```

1. The listener's `before`/`afterVariableChanged()` method will be called each time an entity's `previous` planning variable changes.
2. When that happens, the listener can not only update the `startTime` shadow variable of the `entity` object passed as the second argument, but also any other `MyEntity` instance in the solution, either by navigating through the chain the `entity` argument is part of or by getting the score director's working solution to access other chains.

See https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/shadow-variable/shadow-variable.html for further information about shadow variables.

Comment: Ah, right.  O.k., that answers that part, but the more fundamental issue is, I think, the fact that this introduces a dependency on other chains in the solution, and I can't tell OptaPlanner how to handle that.  At least, I don't know how.  Can I use `@PlanningVariableReference` for this?

Comment: The dependency on other chains is implicit. When a chained entity's `previous` variable changes, the listener will receive the changed entity in `afterVariableChanged()` but it's not limited to updating only that entity's shadow variable. It can update other entities in that chain or even in other chains.

Comment: I see!  That simplifies things.  I've been under the assumption that entities could only impact entities after themselves in the same chain.  I've read (and just now re-read) the docs many times and stepped through the VariableListener internals, but it's never been clear to me what exactly is "legal."  This is related to another question I asked:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69540240/what-constitutes-a-change-in-a-referenced-planning-variable

I would offer an addendum to the docs if I could!  I would ask that the OptaPlanner devs make it very explicit how the graph is created.

Comment: Ryan, feel free to propose an amendment to the shadow variable chapter here: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/main/optaplanner-docs/src/modules/ROOT/pages/shadow-variable/shadow-variable.adoc. It doesn't have to be perfect. A sentence or two will help us understand what's missing in the docs and users should know to be able to use custom shadow variables comfortably.

Comment: O.k., I'll take care of that today.  Thanks!